# Symfony debug bar no se muestra al lanzar el servidor

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, depuración

Tengo un proyecto en symfony 4 en el cual estoy trabajando y que funciona perfectamente a la hora de usar las partes terminadas. El problema es que al hacer `php bin/console s:r` funciona el servidor y puedo ver el resultado pero no se muestra la barra debug de symfony. Se supone que en mi archivo .env tengo el `APP_ENV=dev`.

Hay usuarios que me dicen que tengo que abrir el app_dev.php en vez de app.php pero creo que a partir de symfony 4 eso se eliminó para dejar solo un único index.php para mejorar la integración con navegadores o algo parecido.

He buscado por sin fin de lugares y no encuentro el fallo ni a que se puede deber esto. Agradecería que si alguien sabe algo del tema me pueda ayudar.

Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que el problema es que por defecto la dependencia del componente dotenv está en el composer pero en dev, eso implica que no está disponible si se está en el entorno de producción.

Piensa que ese servidor que se crea con el servidor:run no tiene ninguna variable de entorno configurada, lo que implica que será una máquina de producción.

Si mueves esa dependencia en el composer.json y la re-instalas yo creo que debería funcionar.

Saludos

Comment: Eliminé y volví a instalar dotenv y sigue el problema. No se como trabajar en el modo desarrollo en symfony 4

Comment: no es eliminar y volver a instalar, el mover del composer required-dev al required.